# What's wrong with this page in Chrome and Opera?

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-float, css-transitions

When viewing http://adam.inbulgaria.org in Firefox, it displays as it should; in Chrome and Opera, however, the floated image containers misbehave. I'm sure this has to do with my use of experimental properties (rotation, transitions on hover), but what can I do to make it better?

To clarify, in Chrome 17.0.963.56 m, when hovering above the images, some empty space appears under them. In Opera 11.11, there's space to the right of the images, even when not hovering.

Comment: Looks the same to me in Chromium (admittedly not quite 'Chrome,' then) 16 and Firefox 10 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Looks good in Chrome 18 Beta.

Comment: I believe you need to be specific around the img transformation as well. You aren't specifying img sizes which is considered poor, be absolute, don't expect the browser to work this out for you. And `aside img { height: 100%; }` not `aside img { max-height: 100%; }`

Comment: @Lazarus: `height: 100%` doesn't expand the width of the container in Chrome; in Opera, the container expands only when the transition is complete, and doesn't shrink when the mouse leaves the aside.

Comment: @egasimus Yes, I saw that. The problem is that you aren't specifying a change in the image size, you are relying on the browser to resize the image because the container is changing size. As you mentioned yourself, you are butting up against the newness of these tags and variation in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up like it should in Chrome 17.0.963.56 on Mac. The only difference i can see is the font size + the horizontal bars look different.